# How to Superimpose 2 Stacked Column Charts in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, overlay

I have two stacked column charts (with no gaps between the columns) that have identical X- and Y-axes with same intervals.  One graph is displayed in red, while the other graph is displayed in blue.  When the graphs are superimposed, there will be some areas that are overlapped.  How do I superimpose these two graphs as well as still show both the red and blue in intersecting areas?

The following are two sample data set for the two column charts. The overlapping will occur in Apr-Jul 2015. I don't think I can combine the information to one graph because when I do that, one of the graphs is stacked on top of the other graph. I want both graphs to start on the X-axis line, so then I can see the overlap between the two colors.

In reality, I will need to plot multiple projects instead of two projects as shown here, and there will be 3 different phases. So, for each phase, I would want the values for the projects to be stacked on top of each other, and I would then want 3 layers to represent the 3 phases.

[image: Phase 1]

[image: Phase 1 Graph]

[image: Phase 2]

[image: Phase 2 Graph]

Comment: Can't you just combine the information onto one graph?

Comment: When I do that, one of the graphs is stacked on top of the other graph.  I want both graphs to start on the X-axis line, so then I can see the overlap between the two colors.

Comment: the overlapping areas would look something like this where you can see both colors.: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_integral#mediaviewer/File:Areabetweentwographs.svg

Answer (score 2):

Excel can do this pretty easily.

1. Create a standard Column Chart (not stacked).  It can also be done with an area chart.
2. Add your two data series (assuming a chart similar to the sample you shared).
3. In your `Select Data Source > Legend Entries (Series)` make sure the series you want shown "on top" is at the bottom of the list (the series are drawn in order top to bottom, so the first series will be at the "back" when drawn in the chart).
4. Format your data series to Series Overlap = 100% and Gap Width = 0%.
5. Format your "front or top" series to be transparent. You'll then see the "back or bottom" series through the transparency.

[image: superimposed stacked column]

For best effect, I adjust the transparency of both series.  For multiple series, I'd start with a transparency setting that adds to 100% when all the series are overlapped (e.g. two series, each at 50%, or three series, each at 33%).  Then adjust to taste.

Alternatively, if you want to emphasize the intersection, you could create a third data series and plot that as an overlay, with a stronger color to highlight it, like this:

[image: emphasized intersection]

Another possibility, using your sample data:

[image: superimposed stack cheat2]

Here's a small multiples sample of the individual components from the sample above:

[image: superimposed small multiples]

And with a third phase added

[image: superimposed small multiples2]

Comment: I have two sets of data where stacking columns are required.  I can't figure out a way where I can just use a column chart (not stacked).  I have updated my two sample data sets.  Is there a way to show the layers between phase 1 and phase 2 then?

Comment: Your problem is fairly complex (and seems to be related to your previous question?). Is the third image I added to my answer more like you're expecting? What overlap are you trying to emphasize?

Comment: I added the images of the two graphs in my problem statement.  The overlapping occurs between April-July 2015 from 0-150 for the Y-axis.  How can I combine those two graphs and make that intersection transparent?

Comment: And yes, this is related to my previous question.  I think putting all the data in one set gets visually complicated when I have more than 10 projects and 3 phases.  It might be visually more appealing to have 3 separate graphs for the 3 phases as well as show all 3 merging into one graph.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand the problem a bit better.  Is the third image (I modified it) similar to what you're looking for? With the area of emphasis on the blue/red overlap in the middle?

Comment: Yup, that is what I'm looking for!

Comment: Ok, I'll work on a description, but I probably can't get to it today.  Basically, it's a cheat.  Two identically formatted charts, one for each phase, overlaid. It may be possible in a single chart, but I'll have to work through the mechanics.

Comment: I want to check in and see if you will be able to work on the description some time this week.  What are the steps you took to get the charts shown above?

Answer (score 0):

Put all the information onto one 3D area stacked chart (for some reason if you do it with 2D, the graphs don't actually layer). Right click the plot area and choose "Format Data Series". Make the front layer transparent by going to the "Fill" tab, choosing "solid fill" (or your choice) and adjusting the transparency. See picture below.

[image: http://imgur.com/xXk1URv]

Comment: It seems like you used the 3-D Area chart for the example.  Is there a way to combine '3-D Area' and 'Stacked Area in 3-D'?